# Parameter pack constructor hiding user defined conversion in class template

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I am writing a simple class template for mathematical vectors. I have within the template a constructor template using a parameter pack so that the vector can be constructed with a variable number of parameters:

```cpp
template <unsigned int N, typename T>
class Vec
{
public:

    T m_components[N];

    Vec()
        : m_components{}
    { }

    template<typename ...Args>
    explicit Vec(Args... args)
        : m_components{args...}
    { }

    // ...
}
```

I have also added user defined conversion to convert between classes using this template:

```cpp
    // ...

    template <unsigned int _N, typename _T>
    explicit operator Vec<_N, _T> () const
    {
        Vec<_N, _T> vec;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N && i < _N; ++i)
            vec.m_components[i] = static_cast<_T>(m_components[i]);
        return vec;
    }

    // ...
```

However when I call on the user-define conversion I have written like so:

```cpp
Vec<2, int> a(2, 8);
Vec<4, double> b;
b = (Vec<4, double>)a;
```

The line where the C-style cast is being used causes the following error:

```cpp
C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Vec<2, int>' to 'T' // points to the expansion of the parameter pack: m_components{args...}
```

I can see when I step through the code that the C-style cast goes straight to the parameter pack constructor. Why is this is and what am I doing wrong? How can I prevent the parameter pack constructor from seemingly hiding the user defined conversion?

Comment: Related: [Constructor is always used instead of explicit conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45130166/5376789)

Answer (score 1):

Add this constructor:

```
    // ...

    template <unsigned int _N, typename _T>
    explicit Vec(const Vec<_N, _T>& other)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N && i < _N; ++i)
            m_components[i] = static_cast<_T>(other.m_components[i]);
    }

    // ...
```

As I understand, and I might be very wrong here (someone with more expertise could explain better), the compiler does not know how to modify the current instance of your template class in order to be assigned with the other one.

The `m_components` was allocated with a fixed size during construction. Even with the overload cast operator you only did half the job. There has to be some mechanism for the current instance to be modified in such a way that accepts the data from another one.